Issue with texture painting
I have multiple walls that I'm trying to texture paint. Each has its own material assigned to it. But they use the same image texture. when I go to texture paint one it affects all materials using the same image texture.
Is there a way to make it only effect just the one? Or do I need to increment my image texture for each material?
The need to increment each texture just seems a bit unintuitive where I am already incrementing the materials. Just curious if there is another option.

What do you mean by "incrementing"?

Hello and welcome. Please use a title that matches the content of the post. It should read like a question, be descriptive but succinct, unique and identifying, summarizing the problem so that anyone searching for similar issues is likely to find this. Remove anything superfluous, avoid using words like "this", "help with", "issue" or "question about", instead describe what "it" is. Remember, your title is the first thing visitors see, answers you get depend heavily on it. See What is the problem of asking “How do I do this?"

It's not the materials that matter here. You could use completely different materials, or the exact same. But if they use the same texture file and your objects' UVs overlap each other's, you will have issues. Either use different textures for each object, or use one but make the UVs do not overlap.

That’s what I figured, I’ll have to increment the texture file name. I’m trying to avoid stretching the texture out too much for my walls so adjusting the UV isn’t an option for me right now. Thanks for the answer.

You don't have to increment anything - you need to rethink what your texture and materials needs entail. You can get away with making ALL of your geometry first, and then set up your texture to encompass all of the wall geo like a texture atlas or you could set a single texture for the wall geo and per material use a secondary image texture or procedural texture to affect that wall texture per material. Ideally, you should only texture altogether once you are done modeling.
